# Is running a Windows on mac the same or very close to running windows traditionally?

Tags: operating-system

It's been my understanding the OS sits on top of the hardware. Is it more or less the same to run windows from a macbook? When installing SQL on a windows partition, does this install similar to an all Windows setup?

I've heard the kernel is the main connector between hardware and basic OS, so would the mac kernel cause potential differences in operation?

Would installing the linux OS also adhere to these rules?

Thanks, and sorry for the simple question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you are correct to say that, installing different operating systems on the same hardware would be the same. You will be able to both install Windows and Linux on the same laptop (whether that would be an Asus brand laptop, or HP, or whatever). Once you install an OS on some hardware, and the OS is able to recognize the hardware, and is able to utilize it, then you are in the clear. What's important is to install on OS that is compatible with the architecture of the computer. So if you get a Linux distro that supports `x86` architecture, then you would have to install it on hardware that is with a `x86` architecture.

**Side note:** Modern OS's are very smart and they have a wide range of architecture support ([list of Linux architecture support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux-supported_computer_architectures), [Windows support for ARM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/arm/), Apple also has a wide range of architecture support).

Since you are asking about a macbook and Windows, then the short answer is: there won't be a problem for you to install Windows on your mac. Apple even gives you [Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/boot-camp) to easily do this (there are also quite a bit of recent [tutorials](http://osxdaily.com/2019/02/01/install-windows-10-mac-boot-camp/) on this topic as well).

So the end experience would be almost the same as having Windows on any other machine.

> I've heard the kernel is the main connector between hardware and basic OS, so would the mac kernel cause potential differences in operation?

This is true. The kernel is the heart of any OS, but  once you have your Windows running, it would be using its own heart and it won't touch the mac kernel. So if you remove your macOS and install only Windows, then only the Windows kernel would be taking control of the Mac hardware. But if you load your macOS, then the Mac kernel would be running and operating on the hardware.

Will Windows run *faster* on Mac hardware than macOS on its hardware? It's debatable and I would assume not a lot of studies have been made in that sphere. But, at least, it will run.

But what about dual-booting your macbook with Linux? Technically, it is possible (and the principle is the same), but Apple have made [restrictions to their firmware](https://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/3065755/apples-t2-chip-is-blocking-linux-from-booting-on-new-mac-hardware), limiting the option of having both a macOS and a Linux distro at the same time. What's so different here than the case with Windows? Well mainly that the firmware of the macbook (the software embedded in the hardware of the laptop) doesn't allow for Linux to be installed. Maybe things have changed, but these are the (not so recent anymore) news I know about (I guess there are still ways of installing Linux on mac hardware).